# so why can't await be used in non async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

It seems like very useful functionality to simply wait for a Promise to be resolved anywhere one really wants to.  It is not obvious to me why it has to be only within a function that itself returns a Promise (marked with async).  So what is the really good reason assuming there is one?

I can sort of see that if one is within an event-loop situation that one doesn't want to tie up the event-loop one is dependent upon to actually get the resolution in the first place.  But what of languages that are not event-loop based but may have async-await functionality as an add-on (e.g. Python).  In such a language it seems to me perfectly fine to tie up the current thread (not co-routine or equivalent) with something like this.

Comment: Seems like whatever is parsing the script needs to know if a function is asynchronous, and async does that. `await` allows your lines of code to be executed in order but the entire function then becomes asynchronous

Comment: `one doesn't want to tie up the event-loop` - fortunately, `await` doesn't do that

Comment: I see it for at least code like:
  someFunction() {
     return await(someOtherFunction())

In such a case the delayed return is a defacto Promise so why not mark it as such?